# Working with PDFBox and PDFLayout to generate PDF document

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdfbox-layout

I find that there are few things that are easier do and manage via simple `PDFBox` APIs, whereas some are convenient using `pdfbox-layout`.

`PDFBox` uses [PDDocument](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html) as the class to create and manage documents, whereas `pdfbox-layout` uses [Document](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/blob/master/src/main/java/rst/pdfbox/layout/elements/Document.java) class for same purpose.

How do I work with these 2 classes while generating a single document containing multiple pages.

Comment: This sounds like something for Apache FOP.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I edited the question to point exactly to my concern.